# Android app to upload to Flickr - Flickrj?

Tags: java, android

Good afternoon everybody,

I'm currently trying to get an Android app to upload images to `Flickr`.  So far I'm attempting to work from these examples:

https://github.com/luminousman/Flickr

https://github.com/yuyang226/FlickrjApi4Android

Based on not having `Gradle files` and both being at least a few years old, I'm under the impression that these were both done in `Eclipse`.  I'm attempting to get things working within `Android Studio`.

Both have many imports like this:

`import com.googlecode.flickrjandroid.xxx;`

Is there some way to import the https://github.com/yuyang226/FlickrjApi4Android as a library or similar within `Android Studio`, or is it necessary to copy/paste every `Java` file?  Would that even work?  I'm having a hard time getting started here, if anybody has had success working with the above in `Android` Studio and can provide some direction that would be very helpful.